# A string field, with an encoded string, of a FireDac SQLite database is cut off when using Delphi Module but not C++Builder?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firedac

I'm not sure what is going on here.  I have a third party import routine that is a Delphi module (Delphi library used in C++Builder) but it's cutting off an encoded string whereas the same addition to the same database in C++Builder works fine?

Strings are Unicode.

A hex dump of exact string contains: `5D 54 1B 40 51 03 4A 1F 0A 0B 55 0B 06`

After adding to the database (from the Delphi module) the string only contains `5D 54 1B 40 51 03 4A 1F 0A 0B 55` (it cuts off two characters)

The **Delphi** method is using a `dataset`, `Append`, `Post` and the field value is assigned as either:

```
with DataSet do
begin
  // ...
  Fields[index].AsString := VarToStr(v);
end;
```

or:

```
Fields[index].Value := v;
```

Either way you get the same result.   I have taken the value back out of `Fields[index].AsString` and dump the string to confirm it's correct at that point and it is.

In **C++Builder** it's the same `dataset`, `Append`, `Post` with the field value assigned as:

```
dataset->Fields->Fields[index]->AsString = strEncoded;
```

Not every single encoded value has a problem, but this particular one does.

Seems like it's something deeper dealing with differences in `FireDAC / SQLite` from Delphi code vs C++Builder Code?

Anybody have any ideas what might be going on and how to fix it?

**Update:**

If I add another normal character to the end of the string, such as 'A', it then works and the entire string is okay.  If it's `5D 54 1B 40 51 03 4A 1F 0A 0B 55 0B 06 41` the entire string makes it.   It seems something is cutting it off when only control characters exist at the end of the string in Delphi but not C++Builder - you'd think it shares the same FireDac code base?  It doesn't solve the problem, it just may explain it so the question then becomes how to work around it?

**Update2:**  I was reading that `TrimRight()` (Trim) removes all spacing *and* control characters.  So perhaps something internal in Delphi is doing that.  My check on the contents of the Field was immediately prior to the `Post` so I don't see anything in the 3rd party lib that does a `Trim()` or `TrimRight()`.  Maybe internally doing it?

Comment: By default FireDAC has `FormatOptions.StrsTrim = True`